# “Urgent” edit due to new Imgur ToS and loss of images

Tags: discussion

I reviewed two “urgent” edits that were done because the editor referred to a Meta post [Imgur TOS change on May 15th could cause the loss of thousands of StackExchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/287258)

The [first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388559/287258) and the [linked dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424279) resoundingly say…

> ***Nope!***
>  
>  SE Uses a corporate version of Imagur which guarantees image persistence

I’ve rejected these edits based on this info from Meta.  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Thanks Allan for bring this up here. Good to get a bit of discussion happening on this.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is there's no need to panic or change most posts:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424280

> SE runs a [corporate version of Imgur](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/), so image persistence is guaranteed.

I'd hold off on editing or making approvals based on the post you referenced... Good work rejecting those edits and raising the issue here.

The only posts where we might have a problem are those where someone uploaded directly to Imgur and did not use the corporate version.

This query may assist us in detecting any outliers from the "don't panic" mass of images hosted for this site via Imgur.

- https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1742770/non-se-imgur-links-on-ad

Comment: IMHO this is only part of the story. [This Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388559/193295) mentions two types of IMGUR links: Those created with the "include picture" functionality (-> stored in the corporate version) and those uploaded by users before posting (-> not covered). I've adapted the [query mentioned for AD](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1742770/non-se-imgur-links-on-ad), there are 14 posts impacted.

Comment: I've edited two without a lot of thinking, but after looking at all of them, the loss of the pictures (or even just links to pictures) probably won't cause issues.

Comment: 14 is a rather tiny number - I don’t mind spending an hour or so fixing images if it so warrants @nohillside

Comment: @allan look at the posts and decide for yourself :-)

Comment: Thank so much for catching an important edge case @nohillside I hope my edit does it proper justice.

Comment: @nohillside - there are actually [over 500 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/1742595/top-posts-with-non-stack-imgur-images-order-by-of-views) with images hosted on `i.imgur.com` that are potentially at risk. I've linked to a query that will link the exact posts that use those images.

Comment: @Mithical So, in the context of total number of posts on AD, it's still a miniscule amount. Still, may be worth pursuing edits in the case of the most viewed posts.

Comment: @Monomeeth - Indeed. The edits I suggested to start that process are what sparked this meta post ;)